# Linux Clone "kills" main thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, clone, portaudio

I'm *trying* to implement threads in C on Linux (with clone(), obviously) but I'm having a weird problem.

First, here are my mutex functions :

```
void mutex_lock(int* lock) {
  while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(lock, 0, 1)) {
    syscall(SYS_futex, lock, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL, NULL, 0);
  }
}

void mutex_unlock(int* lock) {
  if (__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(lock, 1, 0)) {
    syscall(SYS_futex, lock, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 0, NULL, NULL, 0);
  }
}
```

And my Thread struct

```
typedef int (*ThreadCallback)(void*);

typedef struct Thread {

  void* alloc;

  char lockSpace[sizeof(int) * 2]; /* Used to align lock pointer properly */
  int* lock;
  int started;
  int tid;

  void* stack;
  size_t stackSize;

  ThreadCallback fn;
  void* args;

}* Thread;
```

In my code, I allocate and initialize a Thread struct I will use later

```
void* start = memAllocThread(sizeof(void*) + sizeof(struct Thread) + TH_STACK_SIZE);
if (start == NULL) {
  return TH_MEM;
}

struct Thread* th = start + TH_STACK_SIZE + sizeof(void*);
th->alloc = start;

size_t lockSpacePtr = (size_t)(th->lockSpace);
lockSpacePtr += 4 - ((lockSpacePtr % 4) % 4); /* To align ptr on? at? 4 bytes */

th->lock = (int*)lockSpacePtr;
*th->lock = 0;
th->started = 0;

th->stack = start + TH_STACK_SIZE;
th->stackSize = TH_STACK_SIZE;

th->fn = fn;
th->args = args;
```

Where "TH_STACK_SIZE", "fn" and "args" are "0x7fff" "ThreadCallback" and "void*" respectively

Now I have my Thread struct initialized, I initialize PortAudio and the default stream with one input channel and zero output channels. Then I start my thread

```
THResult thStart(struct Thread* th) {

  int tid;

  mutex_lock(th->lock);

  if (th->started) {
    mutex_unlock(th->lock);
    return TH_RUNNING;
  }

  tid = clone(_thFunction, th->stack, CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_IO | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_THREAD, th);

  if (tid < 0) {
    mutex_unlock(th->lock);
    return TH_CLONE_ERRNO;
  }

  th->started = 1;
  th->tid = tid;

  mutex_unlock(th->lock);
  return TH_OK;
}
```

"int _thFunction(void*)" is currently empty (when filled, it should start th->fn, but there's no problem here)

And now, after a call to Pa_StartStream(), I can write anything I want, it's not executed (and by the way, printf goes wild if I spread some in the code).

- I **tried** to track down segment violations
- I removed Pa_StartStream : It worked but printf was still too wild
- I removed my thread's start and everything was fine

Any idea ?

EDIT 1 :

- When the created thread ends, program ends
- gdb says nothing about that, I tried breakdowns to analyze the stack but nothing wrong with it

Comment: `printf` (and numerous other library functions) expect the caller to be a `pthread` thread, not a low-level task created by `clone` in some *ad hoc* way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably figured out why it doesn't work.

I read about how `errno` is thread-safe and I think it's because `pthread`s create thread-local variables (used by the (g)libc) my implementation doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

On breaking dowh the question, there's two things that stand out.

1) trying to call printf from an ad-hoc clone. There might well be standard-library junk in the way.

<strike>2) Providing only 4k stack.</strike>

Replace that `printf(...)` with a `write(2, ...)` call and see if you get better behavior. You'll still have a headache on your hands but it won't drop out from under you immediately.

Or maybe try `gdb`

`exit()` exits all threads. Maybe you need to exit some other way. Returning from the spawned thread function is a bad idea as this will hose the stack of the main thread.

Comment: I've added "EDIT 1" to bring more details. I also removed `printf's` from my thread, but it's still the same. But I'm not providing 4k stack, it's actually 0x7fff = 32767B.